# WIALib.dll and WIAVideo.dll is not supporting on Windows 7

Tags: c#

When running on Windows 7

> Exception Occurring At WIAVideoLib.ViaVideoClass.CreateVideoByName ()
>   "Class not registered HRESULT: 0x80040154"

No problem When running it ,On Windows XP. 
Plz Help...

Answer (score 1):

It is explicitly mentioned in the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630377%28VS.85%29.aspx) for WIA Video:

> Note  WIA does not support video devices in Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, or later. For those versions of the Windows, use DirectShow to acquire images from video.

[DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) is a commonly used C# wrapper library.

Comment: private bool SetDShowDefaultDevice()
        {
            DirectShowLib.DsDevice[] devs = DirectShowLib.DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(DirectShowLib.FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            if (devs.Length == 0)
                return false;

            DxDeviceName = devs[0].Name;
            return true;
        }

Comment: private bool OpenDefaultDevice()
        {
            try
            {
                if (UseDShow == false)
                    WiaVideoObj.CreateVideoByWiaDevID(DefaultDeviceObj.Id, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0);
                else
                    WiaVideoObj.CreateVideoByName(DxDeviceName, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0);
                Thread.CurrentThread.Join(1000);
                WiaVideoObj.Play();
                Thread.CurrentThread.Join(1000);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                 
            }
            return true;
        }

Comment: I have used DirectShowLib

Comment: This doesn't get better until you stop using WiaVideoObj.  At least look at the capture sample included with DirectShow.NET.